# Has date type changed in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, datetime, date

I am confused reading statements in ["Why is 1899-12-30 the zero date in Access / SQL Server instead of 12/31?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963617/why-is-1899-12-30-the-zero-date-in-access-sql-server-instead-of-12-31)

Was there date type in SQL Server before 2008 version? I cannot find.
In SQL Server 2008 zero date is 0001-01-01. Were there any date type before (in previous SQL Server versions) how is it backward compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Prior to SQL Server 2008, there was only the [datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)  and [smalldatetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) types.

**Data type...............Range..................................................................Accuracy**
datetime..................January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999.....3.33 milliseconds

smalldatetime..........January 1, 1900, through June 6, 2079............... 1 minute

Please see: [Date and Time Data in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx), specifically the bit that says "*Date/Time Data Types Introduced in SQL Server 2008*"

Comment: I asked about date type but not about other types

Comment: @vgv8: And I just told you there wasn't one!! Rudeness will not get you help.

Comment: Being exact or specific is not synonym of rudeness. You answered to something I had not ever asked. I see it in opposite way. Where is any date type in your answer?

Comment: @vgv8: I have answered your question.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed a 3d (or, it happened, 2nd) opinion

Comment: @gbn, the notion of rudeness is subjective. IMO, rudeness is answering without bothering to understand (& even to read/listen)  question. Some I simply deleted having realized that the answerers are going to mutually answer their own answers. I do not insist in discussing persons instead of things. Plz note the difference and stop giving your personal evaluations like in answer to my latest (deleted by me) question:"Don't quite understand what the question is asking. It sounds like you're thinking too much about a non-existent issue". That was not rude, that was an attempt to humiliate

Comment: @vgv8: .If the answer wasn't what you wanted, then perhaps the question needed to be rephrased? Anyway, you have an answer to your question, so all's good.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server datetime datatype the minimum date that can be stored is [1 Jan 1753](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server/3310588#3310588).

However the datetimes are stored as numeric offsets to a base date of `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`

```
SELECT CAST(-0.25 AS DATETIME) /*1899-12-31 18:00:00.000*/
SELECT CAST(0 AS DATETIME) /*1900-01-01 00:00:00.000*/
SELECT CAST(0.25 AS DATETIME) /*1900-01-01 06:00:00.000*/
```

`1899-12-30` has no significance in SQL Server.

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('1899-12-30' AS DATETIME) AS FLOAT) /*Returns -2*/
```