# DateValue and SQL DATETIME - 30/12/1899 converted to 01/01/01?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

Please have a look at the database structure below:

```
CREATE TABLE TestStartDate (PersonID int, StartDate datetime NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO TestStartDate VALUES(1,'1899-12-30')
```

and the code below:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim objCommand As SqlCommand, objCommand2 As SqlCommand
        Dim objCon As SqlConnection
        Try
            objCommand = New SqlCommand
            Using objCommand
                Dim strConString As String = "Data Source=IANSCOMPUTER;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
                objCon = New SqlConnection
                Using(objCon)
                    objCon.ConnectionString = strConString
                    objCon.Open()
                    objCommand.Connection = objCon
                    objCommand.CommandText = "select startdate from TestStartDate "
                    Dim objDR As SqlDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader
                    If objDR.HasRows Then
                        objDR.Read()
                        Using objCon
                            objCommand2 = New SqlCommand
                            Using objCommand2
                                objCommand2.Connection = objCon
                                objCommand2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestStartDate (StartDate) VALUES (@StartDate)"
                                objCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", DateValue(objDR("StartDate"))) 'line 24
                                'objCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", objDR("StartDate")) 'line 25
                                objCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery() 'Line 26
                                Dim date1 As Date = objDR("startdate")
                            End Using
                        End Using
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally

        End Try
    End Sub
```

The code throws an exception on line 26 (line 26 is annotated):

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

I can resolve this by commenting out line 24 and uncommenting line 25. Why does `DATEVALUE` cause this exception?

I have looked at the following webpage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d6k22a5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx.  This suggests that DATEVALUE might be converting 30/12/1899 to 01/01/01 (01/01/01 is not an acceptable value in SQL Server)? If this is the case, then why is 30/12/1899 converted to 01/01/01?

Comment: Two possibilities: The date time value yielded by `objDR` is out of range, or it becomes invalid during the conversion by `DateValue`. What value does `DateValue(objDR("StartDate"))` yield? Have you tried replacing the `DateValue` function by writing, `objDR.GetDateTime(objDR.GetOrdinal("StartDate"))`?

Comment: @stakx, I have edited the question, please have another look.

Comment: Check this link for some of the history with the '1899 date feature': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963617/why-is-1899-12-30-the-zero-date-in-access-sql-server-instead-of-12-31

Comment: You have formatted your date as YYYY/MM/DD where as the SQL expects it to be DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: Are you trying to use 1899-12-30 or 1900-01-01 as some type of "magic" value? Why not just use NULL instead?