# Initializing DATE in MFC ATL control

Tags: atl

I have a method that returns DATE type, is there a way to initialize it before I make a use of it, other than the following:

```
DATE retValue = 0.0;
```

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with this initialization? You can make it `DATE x = 41943.0;` to initialize it to 31-Oct-2014, for example.

Comment: Right, so Date retvalue =0.0 will init it to Min DateTime basically ?

Comment: You are free to choose the initialization value. It can be anything, including invalid date. The value is number of days since [base date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963617/why-is-1899-12-30-the-zero-date-in-access-sql-server-instead-of-12-31).