# How does date difference work in SQL Server 2012

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2012

I am running following query in SSMS. The result of this query does not make any sense.

**Question** : What logic is exactly followed by SQL Server in determining this difference as it relates to this query?

```
  SELECT
  CAST('1/1/1900 11:00:00 PM' AS DATETIME) AS Date1,
  CAST('1/1/1900 7:00:00 AM' AS DATETIME) AS Date2,
  CAST('1/1/1900 7:00:00 AM' AS DATETIME) - CAST('1/1/1900 11:00:00 PM' AS DATETIME)
  AS Date2MinusDate1
```

**Result of this query**

[image: Date Difference in SQL Server 2012]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that internally datetime data is stored as 8 byte consisting of 2 integers: one that represents days after `19000101` and other representing ticks after midnight. So actually you are substracting 2 integers here:

```
Day of DT1 - Day of DT2
Ticks of DT1 - Ticks of DT2
```

Days are 0s since `19000101` is saved internally as `0`. So first substraction gives you `0`, i.e. `19000101`.

The difference of ticks will give you `16` hours, but pay attension, it will be ticks(`16` hours) from midnight, so actually you should substract `16` hours from midnight not `7am`. Thus `00:00 - 16 hours` is equal to `08:00`. Of course here you shoulb decrement the result of substruction of day, i.e. `0-1=18991231`.

So you end up with `18991231 08:00` and this is correct output.

But you should be very careful when using operators for date manipulation because there are nuances. Use native functions for such manipulation, like `DATEADD`. You can read this article, especially from page 2 http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/34594/0/page/2

Comment: No it is not. Read this from page 2 http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/34594/0/page/2

Comment: I think you should write this fact as part of your answer that substraction is not reliable for datetime values.

Answer (score 1):

The 12/31/1899 is SQLs equivalent to a zero date.

This is a holdover from bad date compatible software.

See this answer: [Why is 1899-12-30 the zero date in Access / SQL Server instead of 12/31?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3963650/575051)

I would recommend [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) for finding differences.

```
SELECT
  CAST('1/1/1900 11:00:00 PM' AS DATETIME) AS Date1,
  CAST('1/1/1900 7:00:00 AM' AS DATETIME) AS Date2,
  DATEDIFF ( hh , CAST('1/1/1900 7:00:00 AM' AS DATETIME) , CAST('1/1/1900 11:00:00 PM' AS DATETIME)) AS Date2MinusDate1
```

Comment: But it looks like datetime subtraction is reliable, because if we add Date1 + Date2MinusDate1, then we get Date2. So, it seems that there is consistency in datetime arithmetic in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: It may have something to do with date formatting. if your run:  SELECT
  CAST('1900-01-01 23:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) AS Date1,
  CAST('1900-01-01 07:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) AS Date2,
  CAST('1900-01-01 23:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) - CAST('1900-01-01 07:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)
  AS Date2MinusDate1 you get 4:00PM which would accurately translate to the 16 hour difference.