# data difference in `as.POSIXct` with Excel

Tags: r, excel, datetime, time

My actual data looks like:

```
8/8/2013 15:10
7/26/2013 10:30
7/11/2013 14:20
3/28/2013 16:15
3/18/2013 15:50
```

When I read this from the excel file, R reads it as:

```
41494.63
41481.44
41466.60
41361.68
41351.66
```

So I used `as.POSIXct(as.numeric(x[1:5])*86400, origin="1899-12-30",tz="GMT")` and I got:

```
2013-08-08 15:07:12 GMT
2013-07-26 10:33:36 GMT
2013-07-11 14:24:00 GMT
2013-03-28 16:19:12 GMT
2013-03-18 15:50:24 GMT
```

Why there is a difference in time? How to overcome it?

Comment: Not sure what's going with the answer here, but maybe try this `as.POSIXct(x*60*60*24, tz = "GMT", origin = "1900-01-01")` if this is your x: `x <- c(41494.63, 41481.44, 41466.60, 41361.68, 41351.66)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg But the minutes are not correct.

Comment: @David If i change the date, my result date will also change. But result dates are correct in the above case. My problem is with minutes only.

Comment: @Pascal maybe these are rounding issues as `41494.63` had probably more digits, dunno. I didn't post this as an answer, rather as an alternative to the highly upvoted answer which has nothing to do with the question below. I'm sure OP can tweak it to his needs.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, might be related to a rounding.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that you already tried that. Anyway, this is the way to go and it's probably Excel is messing up something there. You will have to tweak it to match your needs.

Comment: So, How can I avoid rounding and get accurate time?

Comment: Your Excel data has no seconds there, while R `POSIXct` has to have seconds

Comment: At this point Kavi could you share how you loaded data into R? I am curious to find out how a raw data like `8/8/2013 15:10` is read in R like `41494.63`. Thank you.

Comment: @SabDeM `x<-as.matrix(read.xlsx("Data.xlsx",sheet=1))` this is how I read my data. `read.xlsx` from openxlsx library

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that either R of Excel is rounding the number to two decimals. When you convert the for example the cell with `8/8/2013 15:10` to text formatting (in Excel on Mac OSX), you get the number `41494.63194`.

When you use:

```
as.POSIXct(41494.63194*86400, origin="1899-12-30",tz="GMT")
```

it will give you:

```
[1] "2013-08-08 15:09:59 GMT"
```

This is 1 second off from the original date (which is also an indication that `41494.63194` is rounded to five decimals).

Probably the best solution to do is export your excel-file to a `.csv` or a tab-separated `.txt` file and then read it into R. This gives me at least the correct dates:

```
> df
            datum
1  8/8/2013 15:10
2 7/26/2013 10:30
3 7/11/2013 14:20
4 3/28/2013 16:15
5 3/18/2013 15:50
```

Comment: `41494.63194` with the last 4 recurring gives exactly the right time. The rounding is definitely guilty here.

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
x <- c("8/8/2013 15:10","7/26/2013 10:30","7/11/2013 14:20","3/28/2013 16:15","3/18/2013 15:50")
```

(which is read as a character vector),

try

```
x <- as.POSIXct(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT")
```

It reads correctly as a POSIXct vector to me.

Comment: Since OP specified `tz` argument I think it is better to do not forget it because in Italy where we live `x` will have `CEST` as time zone.

Comment: In my case, x <-c(41494.63, 41481.44, 41466.60, 41361.68, 41351.66) not as u did. when read from excel, date time is read as these values.

Comment: @kavi - you should specify that you are using Excel in your question - this makes a difference as Excel is nuts in dealing with dates.

Comment: okay! Sorry for making the ques look different. I did the changes.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is a matter of how R reads the data. Just an example here with `lubridate` seems to work well.

```
x <- "8/8/2013 15:10"
library(lubridate)
dmy_hm(x, tz = "GMT")
[1] "2013-08-08 15:10:00 GMT"
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question neither I guess.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think you are right but the last question of the OP was "how to overcome it?" then I provided a way to overcome the problem by using `lubridate`. A pragmatic approach that does not explain why the problem happens but allows the OP to defeat it. I am sure a power R user will solve this and will gain a ton of up vote.

Comment: But OPs input is a number such as `41494.63`, not `"8/8/2013 15:10"`

Comment: @DavidArenburg... mmm... I think you are right. At this point maybe the OP has to share with use the code he/she used to read data in order to better understand what is going on. I'll ask.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it works over here on a Windows system. This is what a source Excel 2010 file looks like:

```
date                num         secs        constant    Rtime
(mm/dd/yyyy)        (in Excel)  (num*86400) (Windows)   (secs-constant) 
08/08/2013 15:10    41494.63    3585136200  2209161600  1375974600
07/26/2013 10:30    41481.44    3583996200  2209161600  1374834600
11/07/2013 14:20    41585.60    3592995600  2209161600  1383834000
03/28/2013 16:15    41361.68    3573648900  2209161600  1364487300
03/18/2013 15:50    41351.66    3572783400  2209161600  1363621800

Rtime <- c(1375974600,1374834600,1383834000,1364487300,1363621800)
as.POSIXct(Rtime,origin="1970-01-01",tz="GMT")
#[1] "2013-08-08 15:10:00 GMT" "2013-07-26 10:30:00 GMT"
#[3] "2013-11-07 14:20:00 GMT" "2013-03-28 16:15:00 GMT"
#[5] "2013-03-18 15:50:00 GMT"
```

Why this constant? Firstly, because Excel and Office generally is a mess when dealing with dates. Seriously, look over here: [Why is 1899-12-30 the zero date in Access / SQL Server instead of 12/31?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963617/why-is-1899-12-30-the-zero-date-in-access-sql-server-instead-of-12-31)

`2209161600` is the difference in seconds between the `POSIXct` start of 1970-01-01 and 1899-12-30, which is the 0 point in Excel on Windows.

```
dput(as.POSIXct(2209161600,origin="1899-12-30",tz="GMT"))
#structure(0, tzone = "GMT", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
```