# CAST vs ssis data flow implicit conversion difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl

I have a SSIS package which transfers some data from Oracle to SQL Server.

In Oracle dates are stored as float, e.g. `42824 == '2017-04-01'` - application which uses the database is written in Delphi.

While `select CAST(42824 as datetime)`
in Management Studio results in `'2017-04-01 00:00:00.000'`, the same value (42824) inserted by package into datetime column in SQL Server table shows `2017-03-30 00:00:00.000`.

*Note: Source data type for this number is `DT_R8`, changing the type to `DT_UI4` in Data Conversion component changes nothing*

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## About date serials

The value stored in Oracle (`42824`) is known as date serial , it is also used in `Microsoft Excel`.

Date Serial represents the number of Days between the date value and the initial value that is `1899-12-30`

*You can Read more about Date Serials at:*

- [Why is 1899-12-30 the zero date in Access / SQL Server instead of 12/31?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963617/why-is-1899-12-30-the-zero-date-in-access-sql-server-instead-of-12-31)
- [convert Excel Date Serial Number to Regular Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850605/t-sql-to-convert-excel-date-serial-number-to-regular-date)

## CAST method

From [Microsoft Docs - CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql):

> Only supported when casting from character data to datetime or smalldatetime. When character data that represents only date or only time components is cast to the datetime or smalldatetime data types, the unspecified time component is set to 00:00:00.000, and the unspecified date component is set to 1900-01-01

So `CAST` function consider the value `1900-01-01` as an initial value when casting dates. So we need to subtract 2 days when using it to convert Date Serials

There are 2 ways to convert it to date using SQL Server:

```
select DATEADD(d,42824,'1899-12-30')

select CAST(36464 - 2 as SmallDateTime)
```

## SSIS Implicit conversion

Also according to this [Microsoft docs article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677303(v=sql.110).aspx)

> DBTYPE_DATE (This is an automation DATE type. It is internally represented as a double.. The whole part is the number of days since December 30, 1899 and the fractional part is the fraction of a day. This type has an accuracy of 1 second, so has an effective scale of 0.)

So implicit conversion in SSIS consider the value `1899-12-30` as an initial value when casting dates. So there is no need to subtract 2 days when using it to convert Date Serials

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know the difference and, in fact I did write select <data_as_integer> - 2 in my Oracle query. The problem is that finally I got -4! Somehow it looks like Integration services "knew" this should be treated like date and substracted another 2. As I wrote, if I insert the same (integer) value into datetime explicitly from management studio and by SSIS package, I get two different dates.

Comment: In ssis, how you are converting integer to date?

Comment: Explicitly, I am not. I just have integer column from odbc source mapped to datetime column in oledb destination in data flow task. Source SSIS data type is DT_R8.

Comment: `"DBTYPE_DATE (This is an automation DATE type. It is internally represented as a double.. The whole part is the number of days since December 30, 1899 and the fractional part is the fraction of a day. This type has an accuracy of 1 second, so has an effective scale of 0.)"`

Comment: And that is it :) I must say I find it a little strange that MS uses different approaches in different tools, or even one tool, integration services are part of sql server. Anyway, thank you very much.