# Convert date DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss to YYYY-MM-DD in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, ado.net, etl

I am developing an SSIS package and it reads the data from `SAP`. I have created `ADO.Net` source which reads the data from `ODBC connection`.

From the `SAP` data, there is a table which has the date column and the format of the date value is `12.03.2014 00:00:00`

Now I want to convert it into datetime format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Can I do this in `SQL command` of `ADO.Net` source tool?

Comment: TRy this REPLACE((DT_WSTR, 10)(DT_DBDATE)GETDATE(),"-","")

Comment: Thanks for your reply, let me try this.

Comment: @Srini131 Getting this error - ERROR [42000] [IBM] [System i Access ODBC Driver] [DB2 for i5 / OS] SQL0104 - Token DT_WSTR invalid. Valid token: (. (CWBODBC.DLL)

Answer (score 2):

```
--Yes you Can do it In SQL SERVER

Declare @Date Datetime
SET @Date='12.03.2014 00:00:00'

SELECT @Date=CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@Date,112)
SELECT @Date
```

Comment: User asked in SSIS

Comment: @Srini131  The OP actually asked for *Can I do this in **SQL command** of ADO.Net source tool?*

Comment: 112 gets you `YYYYMMDD`, you could 126 and do a left on that which would include the hyphens.  I'm not sure if this syntax will work the the driver for SAP though

Answer (score 1):

**I don't really know how to achieve this using SQL Command using SAP driver but here are some useful infos**

If you are working with *DateTime* Data Type , *Datetime* are not stored with their formats they are stored as **Number OR string** Values *(The are many ways that date are stored (related to the data provider used); decimals or two integer , ...)* .

For more info take a look at :

- [SAP forumns - date and time field values](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/462707)
- [Basic SAP Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185537(v=bts.10).aspx)
- [how are dates stored in sql server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/how-are-dates-stored-in-sql-server/)
- [CAST vs ssis data flow implicit conversion difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635787/cast-vs-ssis-data-flow-implicit-conversion-difference/43643995#43643995)
- [How are dates stored in Excel?](http://www.microsofttraining.net/fg-53/how-are-dates-stored-in-excel.html)

*Date formats are related to your Regional , application , DBMS settings*

If you want to show dates with other formats you have to change the related setting. Or you can convert it to `String` datatype with a specific format using a script component:

**If Dates are stored as string**

If the Date column is a string you can use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method in a script component. *(assuming that `outDate` is the output column and `inDate` is the input column)*

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;


CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    Row.outDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.inDate,"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss",provider).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

for more info on this method you can refer to this links:

- [DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)
- [C# DateTime.Parse](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-parse)

**If dates are stored as dates**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;


CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    Row.outDate = Row.inDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a drived column component and convert the date as expected like following example:

```
(DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("yyyy",GETDATE()) + RIGHT("0" + "-" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("mm",GETDATE()),2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("dd",GETDATE()),2)
```

[image]