# Wrong conversion to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-convert

In Excel, when I convert these 'General' numbers to dates, which is what they really are, I get different numbers than when I `CONVERT()` them in SQL Server. The data is coming from an import.

```
General     Excel conversion to date       SQL Server conversion to datetime
37621       31-12-2002                     2003-01-02 00:00:00.000
39082       31-12-2006                     2007-01-02 00:00:00.000
39447       31-12-2007                     2008-01-02 00:00:00.000
etc.
```

How can I get the real dates as in Excel with a query in SQL Server? As mentioned, I already used `CONVERT(datetime, [General])`, but then I get the outcomes as in the column SQL Server conversion to datetime.

Comment: What is the `convert()` code you are using in SQL Server?  Also where is the data coming from? A table? An import?

Comment: Excel/Windows and SQL Server have different Day-Zeroes.  Off by two days.  IIRC, this was an original mistake in Windows V1 (I suspect it was actually two different mistakes combined).

Answer (score 2):

To convert an Excel value to a date

```
Select DateAdd(DAY,General,'1899-12-30')
 From  YourTable
```

**Demonstration**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([General] int,[Excel conversion to date] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values
 (37621,'31-12-2002')
,(39082,'31-12-2006')
,(39447,'31-12-2007')

Select *
      ,DateAdd(DAY,[General],'1899-12-30') 
from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
General Excel conversion to date    (No column name)
37621   31-12-2002                  2002-12-31 00:00:00.000
39082   31-12-2006                  2006-12-31 00:00:00.000
39447   31-12-2007                  2007-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: John, I appreciate your answer. But it does not seem to work for me when I use the SELECT statement above..I only need to replace 'General' with my real column name right?

Comment: @PRIME Correct.  It was to demonstrate how convert an Excel Date Value into a SQL Server Date via the DateAdd()

Comment: @JohnCappelletti why 1899-12-30?

Comment: @AnkitSuhail Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963617/why-is-1899-12-30-the-zero-date-in-access-sql-server-instead-of-12-31

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thanks. it's Quite interesting. Thanks again.