# Blank dates coming up as weird dates instead of NULL in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am importing data from postgres into sql server. Fields where data type is 'timestamp without (or with) time zone' i used datetimeoffset in sql table but couldn't create package with the same. So i changed the datatype as datetime.
Now, when I import data,all the dates and time are coming perfectly alright but where there is no data ( blank) then its displayed as some weird date instead of NULL in my SQL table. 
Those weird dates are  -
1899-12-30 00:00:00.000
1753-01-01 00:00:00.000

What am i missing and how to resolve this?
Maybe that's a simple thing but I am quite new to SQL so apologies if its really easy but any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
AP

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963617/why-is-1899-12-30-the-zero-date-in-access-sql-server-instead-of-12-31

Comment: Sounds like that the ETL process you are using is migrating the *`NULL`* as date 0, or similar. In SQL Server, `'17530101'` is the lowest date you can store in a `datetime` (`'18991230'` however, is equivilent to `-2`). If the odd dates are knowns, however, after the import, or during, you could use `NULLIF`. For example: `NULLIF(YourDateColumn,'17530101')`.

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server

Comment: Hi @Tanner ,Thanks for your prompt response. I am using SSMS import and export wizard to import data.So after import ,how to use NULLIF function to replace values in tables? Should i use ALTER TABLE command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your meaningful data is from 2000 onwards, then run a update statement like:

```
update table
set column = NULL
where column < cast('01-01-2000' as datetime)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Prabhat. It worked. Please let me know if I can do something while importing to solve this issue rather than updating table afterwards?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user8165644: are you using SSIS import and export or SSMS import data?

Comment: Hi Prabhat, currently usimg SSMS but will use SSIS later... Thanks

Comment: If you're using SSIS, then certainly there's option to `retain null`. For SSMS, I'll have to check (no access to Sybase)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @ prabhat