# What is the jconsole time format?

Tags: java, time, duration, jconsole

I have monitored my java program using jconsole recently. I saved CPU usage data as a csv file. This is what I've got:

```
Time,CPU Usage
43690.008014,1,8
43690.008060,0,1
43690.008106,0,1
43690.008153,0,1
43690.008199,0,1
43690.008245,0,1
```

The `CPU Usage` column is clear, but I cannot say the same thing about the `Time` column. What is `43690.008014`? How can I parse it into `Date`? I haven't seen anything like this in my life.

Comment: Is your answer in the [Using JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) doc? lots of info there.

Comment: The time format is based on the number of days since `1/1/1900` (based on this [`link`](https://coderanch.com/t/203072/java/JConsole-csv-time-format)).

Comment: But if they really based it on excel, then it seem to suffer from the [`time leap bug`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214326/excel-incorrectly-assumes-that-the-year-1900-is-a-leap-year) as well, as its one day off.

Answer (score 2):

The duration recorded in the CSV file is the number of days since `1899-12-31`<sup>1</sup>. In order to get the current date, you can add this duration to `LocalDate.of(1899, 12, 30).atStartOfDay().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)`. I recommend you use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). The function, [`Duration#ofNanos`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#ofNanos-long-) gives you a `Duration` representing the specified number of nanoseconds. The reason why I am recommending you to use this function despite the fact that there is already a function, [`Duration#ofDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#ofDays-long-) is that these functions take a `long` value as the argument and if you cast the duration in your log file (e.g. `43690.008014`) to `long`, its fractional part will be lost giving you an incorrect result.

Therefore, convert these days to nanoseconds, get `Duration` from the resulting nanoseconds and add the same to `LocalDate.of(1899, 12, 30).atStartOfDay().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)` to get the current date and time in `UTC`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime startDateTime = LocalDate.of(1899, 12, 30).atStartOfDay().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        OffsetDateTime current = startDateTime
                .plus(Duration.ofNanos((long) (43690.008014 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000_000_000)));
        System.out.println(current);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2019-08-13T00:11:32.409600512Z
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

---

<sup>1 [Why is 1899-12-30 the zero date in Access / SQL Server instead of 12/31?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963617/why-is-1899-12-30-the-zero-date-in-access-sql-server-instead-of-12-31)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The time format is `daysSinceEpoch.fractionOfCurrentDay`

The `daysSinceEpoch` starting at 1899-12-30 instead of 1900-01-01

The `fractionOfCurrentDay` is a millionth of the current day, ranging from zero to `999999` (23:59:59)

You can use the following function to convert to LocalDateTime:

```
   public static LocalDateTime convert( final String jconsoleDateFormat )
   {
      String[] split = jconsoleDateFormat.split( "\\." );
      long daysSinceEpoch = Long.parseLong( split[0] );
      long dayFraction = Long.parseLong( split[1] );

      LocalDateTime epochDate = LocalDateTime.of( 1899,12,30, 0,0 );
      LocalDateTime currentDate = epochDate.plusDays( daysSinceEpoch );

      long secondsADay = 24 * 60 * 60L; // 86_400
      long secondsSinceDayStarted = secondsADay * dayFraction / 1_000_000;
      return currentDate.plusSeconds( secondsSinceDayStarted );
   }

   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      System.out.println( convert( "43690.008014" ) ); // 2019-08-13T00:11:32
   }
```