# Pandas read_excel: parsing Excel datetime field correctly

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

I have the following sample data stored in Excel file

| CLAIM | CODE1 | AGE | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7538 | 359 | 71 | 28/11/2019 |
| 7538 | 359 | 71 | 28/11/2019 |
| 540 | 428 | 73 | 16/10/2019 |
| 540 | 428 | 73 | 16/10/2019 |
| 605 | 1670 | 40 | 04/12/2019 |
| 740 | 134 | 55 | 24/12/2019 |

When importing to my Jupyter Notebook using the pandas.read_excel API, the date field does not get properly formated:

```
excel = pd.read_excel('Libro.xlsx')
```

[image]

Then I am getting the DATE field different as I have it formatted in the excel file. What argument should I apply to `read_excel` in order to display the DATE column formatted as I have it in the excel file?

`.info()` method, outputs the column as int64

[image]

I already tried using the `pd.to_datetime` function, but I am getting strange results:

[image]

Find the sample excel file I am using for my project in the following link [sample_raw_data](https://github.com/fvgm-spec/csv_files/blob/master/Libro.xlsx)

Here is some code that can be used to reproduce the DataFrame that is read in from excel:

```
excel = pd.DataFrame({
    'CLAIM': {0: 7538, 1: 7538, 2: 540, 3: 540, 4: 4605, 5: 1740, 6: 7605},
    'CODE1': {0: 359, 1: 359, 2: 428, 3: 428, 4: 1670, 5: 134, 6: 415},
    'AGE': {0: 71, 1: 71, 2: 73, 3: 73, 4: 40, 5: 55, 6: 56},
    'DATE': {0: 43797, 1: 43797, 2: 43754, 3: 43754, 4: 43803, 5: 43823,
             6: 43818}
})
```

Comment: You need to use the `date_parser` argument in `pd.read_excel`

Comment: `date_parser` won't work since pandas will recognise `DATE` as an int and as such not apply the date parser. And trying to force the dtype of Date as `datetime64[ns]` will get the same error with everything being a 1970-01-01 date. @Erfan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To convert this Excel Date into `datetime64[ns]` use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime) to get unit in days with offset from `origin` '1899-12-30':

```
excel = pd.read_excel('Libro.xlsx')
excel['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(excel['DATE'], unit='d', origin='1899-12-30')
```

`excel`:

```
   CLAIM  CODE1  AGE       DATE
0   7538    359   71 2019-11-28
1   7538    359   71 2019-11-28
2    540    428   73 2019-10-16
3    540    428   73 2019-10-16
4   4605   1670   40 2019-12-04
5   1740    134   55 2019-12-24
6   7605    415   56 2019-12-19
```

`info`:

```
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   CLAIM   7 non-null      int64         
 1   CODE1   7 non-null      int64         
 2   AGE     7 non-null      int64         
 3   DATE    7 non-null      datetime64[ns]
```

See [Why is 1899-12-30 the zero date in Access / SQL Server instead of 12/31?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3963617/15497888) for more information about why this is the base date.

---

A `converter` for `DATE` can also be used with [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel):

```
excel = pd.read_excel(
    'Libro.xlsx',
    converters={
        'DATE': lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, unit='d', origin='1899-12-30')
    }
)
```

`info`:

```
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   CLAIM   7 non-null      int64         
 1   CODE1   7 non-null      int64         
 2   AGE     7 non-null      int64         
 3   DATE    7 non-null      datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: As of March 2024, use  unit='D'

Comment: Lowercase `'d'` and uppercase `'D'` both work in the current version of pandas (2.2.1). Either letter is converted the appropriate type in [abbrev_to_npy_unit](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2.2.x/pandas/_libs/tslibs/dtypes.pyx#L627-L628) for use in [cast_from_unit_vectorized](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2.2.x/pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx#L128) via [_to_datetime_with_unit](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2.2.x/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py#L512) which is eventually called by `to_datetime` (though I'm at the character limit to add more links)