# Convert Nvarchar Datatype to Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, nvarchar

I am practicing on a database on SQL server where the date column in the table is `Nvarchar(255)` thereby presenting the dates as five digit numbers eg `40542`,`40046` etc. How do I change the dates in the column to actual dates?

The articles I checked only helped me to change rows but I can't change all of them individually as that will take time.

Comment: Sounds like you want an `UPDATE` statement? There are plenty of tutorials out there. You would need another column of `DATETIME2` datatype to store them in. But anyway, please do explain what date `40542` should be?

Comment: Just curious.  Does 40542 represent a date from Excel ?   Like perhaps 12/30/2010 ?

Comment: Just for fun try Select convert(datetime,40542-2.0)    Notice the minus 2.0.   This explains the need for the adjustment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963617/why-is-1899-12-30-the-zero-date-in-access-sql-server-instead-of-12-31

Comment: I would highly recommend taking the tour and learning how to use this site.

Answer (score 1):

If dates from Excel, this is to expand on my comment.

Here are two approaches

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] nvarchar(255))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('40542')
,('40043')
 
Select *
      ,AsDate1 = try_convert(datetime,try_convert(float,SomeCol)-2.0)
      ,AsDate2 = dateadd(day,try_convert(int,SomeCol),'1899-12-30')  -- Note Start Date
 From @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol AsDate1     AsDate2
40542   2010-12-30  2010-12-30
40043   2009-08-18  2009-08-18
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange database. Basically, you want

```
UPDATE TableName
  SET NewDateColName = ConvertionFunction(OldDateColName)
```

But more info is needed on how to convert the 5 digit number encoded as a string, into a date.

```
CAST(OldDateColName as Date)
```

Might work, or you may have to apply some arithmetics after casting to int.

For excel dates:

```
UPDATE TableName
  SET NewDateColName = CONVERT(numeric(18,4),OldDateColName,101)
```

Answer (score 0):

The values of your "dates" suggests that your dates reflect an offset in days since the epoch (zero point on the calendar system) of 1 January 1900.

For instance, the values you cited are:

- `40452`: Sunday, October 3, 2010
- `40046`: Sunday, August 23, 2009

In which case you should be able to say something like

```
create view dbo.my_improved_view
as
select t.* ,
       some_date = date_add( day,
                             convert( int  , t.funky_date_column ),
                             convert( date , '1900-01-01'        )
                           )
from dbo.table_with_funky_date_column t
```

Comment: You're off 2 days.  Day 0 in Excel is Jan 00, 1900 or rather Dec 31, 1899 and they missed the Leap Year in 1900

Comment: @JohnCappelletti — I'm not making the assumption that this is from Excel. It might be, or it might not be.